# How to maintain active state when multiple objects intersect and move one in Fabric.js?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

This is the Fabricjs [demo](http://fabricjs.com/intersection), which show how to detect intersections between objects.

[image]

But there is a problem in the example, when two objects have already intersected and I move another new object, the intersection opacity state of the red rect will disappear until the new object intersects with them again.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There's my confusion. When I move away from one of the triangles or circles, I need to keep opacity state instead of restoring the highlight. What should I do?